# Multiple swiffy sequence matters how it will be played

Tags: google-swiffy

In our project we found strange swiffy behavior and we can`t find why it happenes.

[TestCase1](http://i.vestum.ru/shared/stackoverflow/test1.html)
[TestCase2](http://i.vestum.ru/shared/stackoverflow/test2.html)

Banner A (goes first in first case, second in case two), must have on 3rd slide border around photo that appears in slide.
And it works as expected if he goes last like in case2. But dose not if he goes first like in case1.

Why could it be and how it could be fixed?

Comment: [border that must apear on banner](http://i.imgur.com/h76p0bp.png)